# Pass arguments to powershell invoke-expression command

Tags: powershell, github, invoke-command, windows-scripting, rundeck

My issue is similar to this:
[How to pass arguments to an Invoke-Expression, in Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33206285/how-to-pass-arguments-to-an-invoke-expression-in-powershell)

I have the following command:

```
powershell iex ((New-Object Net.WebClient -Property @{Proxy = [Net.GlobalProxySelection]::GetEmptyWebProxy()}).DownloadString('https://github/test.ps1'))
```

And I'd like to somehow pass the following arguments to this command if possible one line, so just extend my command.

```
"${node.site}" "${node.zone}"
```

If one line impossible, can put 2 line as well.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you're trying to achieve? Your question is a bit unclear as I personally have no idea what `somehow pass the following arguments to this command` means.

Comment: Hi, yes sure, I want to run that script on rundeck and on rundeck we have some default inherited values that we can use. The listed to value I want to pass somehow to the script, define it somehow. The linux job looks like this:  bash <(curl -s --noproxy '*' https://github/install.sh) "${node.site}" "${node.zone}"  I want to achieve this on windows. The running is working but cannot pas the parameters easily. I can make it work if I download the file first and run it locally so in 2 commands it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can search through the help for `PowerShell.exe` --> 'PowerShell.exe /?' from a PowerShell/cmd console.

below is a possible example for your requirement.

```
PowerShell -Command " & {param(`$r) Write-Output `$r }" 'sometext'
```

maybe for you

```
powershell -command " & {param(`$Url) iex ((New-Object Net.WebClient -Property @{Proxy = [Net.GlobalProxySelection]::GetEmptyWebProxy()}).DownloadString(`$Url))}" 'https://github/test.ps1'
```

Comment: So the Url should be on the place of the $url or at the end? Or where should I define my variables.

Comment: At the end, `$Url` is a parameter used inside the ScriptBlock, you can use your variable instead of the 'https://github/test.ps1' the value at the end will be mapped to `$Url` while executing.